# SQLite duplicates rows

Tags: android, database, multithreading, sqlite

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE rss (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title text, body text, img_url text);
```

I write items with following code:

```
public void writeRssModel(ArrayList<RssModel> items){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    for (RssModel model : items){
         try {
             ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
             cv.put(DBConst.BODY, model.getBody());
             cv.put(DBConst.IMG_URL, model.getImgUrl());
             cv.put(DBConst.TITLE, model.getTitle());
             db.insert(DBConst.TABLE, null, cv);
         }catch (Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}
```

When I reuse this code, the rows duplicate; I cannot delete items, because it works in a background thread and in UI thread there is a live Cursor on this table. I need to update the rows.

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180441/android-sqlite-update-insert ?

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `title text unique` and `db.insertWithOnConflict(DBConst.TABLE, null, cv, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);`